# gcc pointer error did you mean to use ‘->’?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct

I have defined structs in header file

```
typedef struct tDLElem {                 
        int data;                 
        struct tDLElem *lptr;     
        struct tDLElem *rptr; 
} *tDLElemPtr;

typedef struct { 
    tDLElemPtr First;
    tDLElemPtr Act; 
    tDLElemPtr Last;
} tDLList;
```

And I have this code

```
void DLInsertFirst (tDLList *L, int val) {
    tDLElemPtr *newPtr = (tDLElemPtr *) malloc(sizeof(struct tDLElem));
    if (newPtr == NULL)
        DLError();
    newPtr->lptr = NULL;
    newPtr->rptr = L->First;
    newPtr->data = val;
    if (L->First != NULL)
    {
        L->First->lptr = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        L->Last = newPtr;
    }
    L->First = newPtr;
}
```

It seems fine to me but when I try to build it, gcc says

> c206.c: In function ‘DLInsertFirst’: c206.c:104:8: error: ‘*newPtr’ is
>   a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?   newPtr->lptr = NULL;
>
> c206.c:109:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]    L->First->lptr = newPtr;

Can you tell me where is my code wrong ? And mostly why is it telling me to use '->' when I use it there ? Thanks

Comment: Your mistake is using a typedef for *pointers*. `tDLElemPtr` is *already* a pointer, you should write 'tDLElemPtr newPtr`. Or even better, stop adding such confusing `typedef`s - as you see, they're a bad practice.

Comment: I have to use typedef there, I cannot change it

Comment: `tDLElemPtr *newPtr = (tDLElemPtr *) malloc(sizeof(struct tDLElem));` allocates the wrong amonut of space  (you have a pointer to a pointer, but you allocate size of a whole struct). I suspect you wanted `tDLElemPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are not using your pointer to struct correctly.

```
typedef struct tDLElem {                 
        int data;                 
        struct tDLElem *lptr;     
        struct tDLElem *rptr; 
} *tDLElemPtr; // note that tDLElemPtr is a pointer!!
```

Using this `typedef` with `tDLElemPtr` means the variable you will declare is a `struct tDLElem *` (**pointer!!!**), thus `tDLElemPtr *newPtr` is a pointer to pointer (`struct tDLElem **`), meaning `newPtr->lptr = NULL;` should actually be `(*newPtr)->lptr = NULL;` (I added here another indirection to access the struct itself).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your first data struct should look like this:

```
struct tDLElem {                 
    int data;                 
    struct tDLElem* lptr;     
    struct tDLElem* rptr; 
};
typedef struct tDLElem* tDLElemPtr;
```

This should make it clearer what's going on.